# How to extract words between two periods using gsub

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a text that looks like this:

```
txt <- "w.raw.median"
```

I want to extract the second word in between two periods (`.`),
giving this output

```
> raw
```

But why this doesn't work

```
gsub(".*\\.", "", txt)
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
gsub(".*\\.(.*)\\..*", "\\1", txt)
[1] "raw"
```

Answer (score 5):

Also consider

```
strsplit(txt,'.',fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]
```

for a (slightly) more readable version

Comment: a subtle variant on that, just for fun: `sapply(strsplit(txt, ".", fixed=TRUE), "[", 2)`